# Why am i not able to send registration mails through my server

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

I am trying to make a registration that sends mails with their username and password after they successfuly register. When I try to register the user is added to the database with all the information I input, everything normal up until the point where the process tries to send the mail.

This is the mail.js :

```
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

let mailer = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "mail.foi.hr",
    port: 25,
    /* auth: {
        user: "",
        pass: ""
    }*/
});

exports.posaljiMail = async function (salje, prima, predmet, poruka) {
    console.log("im hereeee");
    message = {
        from: salje,
        to: prima,
        subject: predmet,
        text: poruka,
    };

    let odgovor = await mailer.sendMail(message);
    console.log(odgovor);
    return odgovor;
};
```

And this is my error:

```
node:internal/process/promises:289
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 160.43.120.3:25
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1595:16) {     
  errno: -4039,
  code: 'ESOCKET',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '160.43.120.3',
  port: 25,
  command: 'CONN'
}
```

Comment: node.js?  I set that tag please remove if that is incorrect.

Comment: Your TCP socket connection to the mail server timed out. I'm assuming that "160.43.120.3" is what "mail.foi.hr" resolves to. Make sure you have the right address, port, etc.

Comment: The connection timed out, so either there's a network problem, a firewall, or that's the wrong server and/or port.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, it looks like the port configured to access the mail server is wrong.
I could not access it on port 25, however it seems available on port 587 with starttls.

As a next step, you may ensure you have the right port/security settings against your mail provider. With a google search I found [this document](http://cip.foi.hr/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/email_clients_2021.pdf) describing configuration for Mozilla Thunderbird, suggesting using port 587 and Starttls would be the right combination.

To do so, you should update your code as such:

```js
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

let mailer = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "mail.foi.hr",
    port: 587,
    secure: false,
    /* auth: {
        user: "",
        pass: ""
    }*/
});
```

Comment: I tried using it, I got this error:

Error: Can't send mail - all recipients were rejected: 554 5.7.1 <retom26902@undewp.com>: Relay access denied

Comment: It is common for email servers to prevent using them to send messages from addresses from another domain than theirs, as a measure to prevent spam.
I may be mistaken, but @undewp.com does not seem to be related to `foi.hr`.